# How make a div container responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background-image assigned in the CSS3 file.
The image is responsive, so it scales according to the screen size BUT the container keeps the height at all screen sizes.

I need to know if there is a way to make the container responsive as well as the background image.

HTML:

```
<div class="responsive> </div>
```

CSS3:

```
.responsive {
    background: url('https://s20.postimg.org/o09gf7fvx/bag.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 270px;
}
```

I must use background-image selector and no img src tag.
Here is the [fiddle file](https://jsfiddle.net/Wtk16/zkbbqj7g/1/).

Thank you.

Comment: Responsive to what? It's already 100% wide, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Like @Paulie_D said, ["responsive design"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) usually refers to a comfortable 100% width, but if you have something else in mind, check out CSS3 [media-queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries).

Comment: If you are trying to size the div to the image size, you can't do that with a background image.

Comment: Why do you have to use `background-image`?

Comment: @Paulie_D responsive web design means the capability of a element to adjust it's size according to the viewport size, from desktop to mobile devices. If you get the fiddle sample at different screen sizes, you'll notice the image scale according to the screen size however, the div container keeps the same height at all screen sizes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update - February 3rd, 2021**

Since I wrote the original answer a new CSS property has been introduced - 'aspect-ratio' - to solve this problem.

```
<div id="responsive">some text</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    background: hotpink;
    aspect-ratio: 100 / 29;
}
```

At the time of writing this CSS property doesn't yet have widespread browser support.

**Working Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/fu0nL57t/

**Ref:** https://web.dev/aspect-ratio/

=====================================================

**Original Answer**

This can be done an additional dummy element, inside the element you want to keep at a fixed ratio. If you specify a padding-top or padding-bottom as a percentage, that is in terms of the width of the container element, and this then keeps the height of the container element at a fixed ratio.

```
<div id="responsive">
    some text
    <div id="dummy"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#responsive {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('https://s20.postimg.org/o09gf7fvx/bag.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    background-size: contain;
}

#dummy {
    padding-top: 29%;
}
```

**Working Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/098jj61q/

**Credits:**

- http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio
- http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you. One question; on the padding-top: 29%; from where the 29% is coming?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its correct. According to @Paulie_D, you can't do that with background image.As per your requirement you can do that using **img** tag only.

What you have to do, without using the div just make the image responsive by treating it as a block element as,

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

or if you insist to use division with background image then cover the backgound image and set min-height as,

```
div.mydiv {
    background:url(background_image.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position:center center !important;
    min-height:300px;
}
```

Comment: I cannot use img src tag. The image must be called from the css file and not from the html file. Could you elaborate on your examples, how the could be integrated to my code? Can you test it on the fiddle? Thanks

Comment: The image scale horizontally but it keeps the same height at all screen sizes.

Comment: That's the point of responsive image/element, if you wanted to scale the division according to viewport, then you can try some trick given by @Chris Hilditch in above answer.